# Create new file with custom file extension?

Tags: cocoa, file, encryption, file-format

How can I create a new file with a file format of say .kuy.This file would be holding encrypted data. And then later I could choose that file with extension .kuy to decrypt. So if I encrypted soundfile.aup, the encrypted file would be soundfile.aup.kuy, then the user would proceed to decrypting that file in which case the output would be soundfile.aup.

Thank you,

Bobby

Comment: Are you asking "how do I write a file to disk?"

Comment: Essentially, yes. But it must have a specific extension.

Comment: I'm no Cocoa expert but wouldn't it just be a case of, you know, putting that extension in your file name when you open the file for writing?

Comment: ? If I encrypt a file say test.wav, it must create a new file test.wav.kuy which holds the encrypted data. All I'm doing is setting clearTestWithData:myData to the .kuy file. I'm not exactly sure if I'm following what you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a file extension to your application by going to your Target's info window and selecting the Properties tab:

[image: Properties tab screenshot]

After that, you just need to add your desired extension when you save a file.

Answer (score 1):

As Steve suggests, first you have to create a custom file format. After that, whenever a custom file gets open - double click or whatever - its path will be passed to application:openFile:. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW29

Once you have the path, do your logic and you should be fine.